# Biggest among three uniform random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Question: Given three random variables $X, Y, Z$ of independent uniform distribution in range [0,1], what's the probability for $X$ to be the biggest one?

I've come up with two solutions but they give totally different answers.

- **Sol1**: Since $X, Y, Z$ are independent and symmetric, anyone of them has equal probability to be the biggest one, so answer is $\frac{1}{3}$.
- **Sol2**: $\Pr[X\text{ is biggest}]=\Pr[X > Y, X > Z] = \Pr[X > Y]\Pr[X > Z] = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$.

I guess the first answer is correct because

$$\Pr[X\text{ is biggest}] + \Pr[Y\text{ is biggest}] + \Pr[Z\text{ is biggest}] $$

should better be 1. But I didn't see why sol2 is incorrect...Thanks in advance for answering!

Comment: The events $X>Y$ and $X>Z$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

The logic for the first solution is sound, and all premises are clearly justified.   It is valid.

The second solution would only be valid if the event $X>Y$ were independent of the event $X>Z$.   You have just demonstrated that that premise is not justified.

---

Also:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X>Z\mid X>Y) & = \frac{\mathsf P(X>Z\cap X>Y)}{\mathsf P(X>Y)}
\\ & = \frac{\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^x \operatorname d z\operatorname d y \operatorname d x}{\int_0^1 \int_0^x \operatorname d y \operatorname d x}
\\ & = \frac 2 3
\end{align}$$

Comment: There are simpler ways to show this probability is $2/3$ than any that involve integrals. (See my posted answer.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, indeed.  Your solution is based off solution 1.  The integration method just confirms that it's a valid approach.

Comment: "based off"?  A typo for "based on"?  Anyway, you do not need to evaluate integrals to show that $\Pr(X>Y\ \&\ X>Z) = 1/3$.  It is enough to show that the three events $[X>Y\ \&\ X>Z]$, $[Y>Z\ \&\ Y>X]$, $[Z>X\ \&\ Z>Y]$ are mutually exclusive and essentially exhaustive, and from that you can conclude that each has probability $1/3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

The two events $X>Y$ and $X>Z$ are not independent.  They both depend on $X$, so that shouldn't be surprising.  Knowing that $X>Y$ makes it more probable than it would otherwise be that $X$ is big; hence more probable than it would otherwise be that $X>Z$.  We have $\Pr(X>Y)=1/2)$ and

$$
\Pr(X>Z\mid X>Y) = \frac{\Pr(X>Z\ \&\ X>Y)}{\Pr(X>Y)} = \frac{1/3}{1/2} = \frac 2 3.
$$
The two probabilities in the numerator and the denominator are $1/3$ and $1/2$ is seen to be true be just the method that appears in the posted question.